# VM machines cannot ping each other via bridge network on Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: server, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

I created vhost1 and vhost2 by using virt-manager which run on a Ubuntu server 22.04
The Host and VMS connected via a bridge network. So here's the thing:
The `ping` working fine between Host and VMS, but it doesn't work between VMS(vhost1 and vhost2)

Network configuration of Host:

br0:  `192.168.110.161/24`

/etc/netplan/netcfg.yaml

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp24s0f1:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
  bridges:
    br0:
      macaddress: aa:bb:cc:11:22:33
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.110.161/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.110.1
          metric: 100
          on-link: true
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 223.6.6.6
      interfaces:
          - enp24s0f1
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4
```

bridge of Host:

```bash
(base) root@qlsj:/etc/netplan# brctl show
bridge name bridge id   STP enabled interfaces
br0   8000.aabbcc112233 yes   enp24s0f1
              vnet6
              vnet7
docker0   8000.0242b2287cce no    veth1beee8b
              veth6554059
virbr0    8000.525400dcd61a no    vnet2
              vnet4
```

route of Host:

```bash
(base) root@qlsj:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.110.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 br0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.110.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
(base) root@qlsj:~#
```

Network configuration of vhost1:

enp9s0: `192.168.110.204/24`

```yaml
network:
  ethernets:
    # interface name
    enp9s0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.110.204/24]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.110.1
          metric: 99
      nameservers:
        addresses: [223.6.6.6,223.5.5.5]
      dhcp6: false
  version: 2
```

vhost1 nic:

```xml
<interface type="bridge">
  <mac address="52:54:00:19:ab:92"/>
  <source bridge="br0"/>
  <target dev="vnet6"/>
  <model type="virtio"/>
  <alias name="net1"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x07" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</interface>
```

Network configuration of vhost2:

enp7s0:  `192.168.110.169/24`

```yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    # interface name
    enp7s0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.110.169/24]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.110.1
          metric: 101
      nameservers:
        # name server to bind
        addresses: [223.6.6.6,223.5.5.5]
      dhcp6: false
  version: 2
```

vhost2 nic:

```xml
<interface type="bridge">
  <mac address="52:54:00:81:59:a2"/>
  <source network="host-bridge" portid="72753e9d-2408-4858-b8b7-806b3666afa0" bridge="br0"/>
  <target dev="vnet7"/>
  <model type="virtio"/>
  <alias name="net1"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x09" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</interface>
```

vhost1 ping vhost2:

```bash
qlsj@vhost1:~$ ping 192.168.110.169
PING 192.168.110.204 (192.168.110.204) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.110.161 icmp_seq=1 Packet filtered
From 192.168.110.161 icmp_seq=2 Packet filtered
From 192.168.110.161 icmp_seq=3 Packet filtered
^C
--- 192.168.110.204 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2034ms

qlsj@vhost1:~$
```

Both Host and vms configuate with `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`, policy of `iptables FORWARD chain` is `ACCEPT`

I tried to change the gateway of vhost1 and vhost2 to `192.168.110.161` which is address of Host's br0. It is still not working.

I have no idea what to do. I tried lots of things, It doesn't work.

Please forgive  my grammatical mistakes, I am not good at English.

If anything I can provide, Please comment below.